# How to import a range into Python from Excel as a list?

Tags: python, excel, pyxll

I am trying to import the range `A1:C4` from Excel into Python as a list, then add '_a' to the end of every element in that list. Currently it is returning the TypeError "can only concatenate list(not 'str') to list"

I've gotten it to import a range before then return that range:

```
#Excel formula: =funky(A1:C4)

listy = ["item_0"]

@xl_func #needed before any function that is called on in the excel spreadsheet
def funky(add): #needs one input to function, in this case it is being given the range A1:C4 in the excel spreadsheet
    global listy
    listy.extend(add) #adds all the elements given to the function into 'listy' (in this case it is the values of range A1:C4 in the excel spreadsheet)
    return(listy[1:]) #returns all elements past element [0]
```

but it still doesn't allow me to do any sort of edits to the values of the range.

This is something I've tried to do, with the same range but a different function:

```
@xl_func
def iter(add): #When I changed line 4 to .extend([add]) I also changed 'add' to '[add]'
    list = ["item_0"]
    list.append(add) #I also tried .extend(add) and .extend([add]) but got the same error
    list = [item + '_a' for item in list] #adds '_a' to the end of every item in 'list'
    return list #returns the edited 'list'
```

What the Excel formula looks like:

```
=iter(A1:C4)
```

This function (`iter(add)`) is what is returning the TypeError. `funky(add)` does not return this error.

Comment: I wonder if you need to force "add" to be a str like ```list.append(str(add))```

Comment: @SurajShourie I can try that and see if it works. Then I'll try a different method to force it to be a list.

Comment: Just tested it, doesn't work to force it as a string because `list.append(str(add))` doesn't recognize `add` as a variable. Note that is when I am also forcing it to be a string variable coming in, aka `def iter(str(add)):`
I'll try with just forcing it in `list.append`

Comment: So with just `list.append(str(add))`, it changes and outputs `[['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3'], ['item_4', 'item_5', 'item_6'], ['item_7', 'item_8', 'item_9'], ['item_10', 'item_11', 'item_12']]_a`

Which is progress, but not much. Maybe I can split this into a list and filter out everything that isn't 'item_`x`'.

Comment: So given that the new output is a list of lists, it doesn't change anything if I split it into another list. which sucks, maybe I can look up how to split elements in a nested list?

Comment: So I figured out how to split the list, but now I need to remove certain characters from the list, specifically the `[[`, `[`, `'`, `]`, and `]]` characters

Comment: Okay so I figured out an incredible jank solution. Before converting the `str(add)` into a list (by using `split()`), I put in a lot of `strip()` functions that remove the unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved my own question by looking around for some better solutions, and I found one that helped a lot after a little bit of messing around with it.

I dissolved `add` into a single big list using `merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(add))`

(Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/21975226)

Then everything worked as intended!

My main problem was that I was trying to add a string to the end of a list object, which is why it was returning the `TypeError`.

What I did to fix that was dissolve the input list (`add`) and use `.extend()` to add it to `list` (which I renamed to `list_0` because of conflict with `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(add))`).
Then the line that adds the string `_a` to the end of every element in `list_0` worked perfectly!